# A max-even subset problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, sets, linear-algebra, coding-theory

I want to know if there is any polynomial algorithm for the problem, or any NP-completeness result.

- Given a set $S$ and $m$ subsets $C_1, \dots, C_m$ of $S$, we want to find a non-empty set $X\subseteq S$ such that $|X\cap C_i|$ is even for as many $i$ as possible.

We can see this problem in another way: given $m$ $\{0,1\}$-vectors of size $n$, find a vector $X$ of size $n$ that has even inner product with the greatest possible number of the vectors.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: I guess you want to find $X$ as large as possible?

Comment: i do a research on computer science and i reached to this problem and i think that it might be a famous problem, but i cant find this with search and i can't solve it myself, so i decided to post it here.no, X can be any non empty subset. the goal is to maximize the number of Ci's.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is:

Input: a $n \times n$ matrix $M$ of integers modulo 2
Goal: find a $n$-vector $x$ such that the Hamming weight of $Mx$ is as small as possible (with all arithmetic modulo 2)

This is the problem of finding a [minimum-weight codeword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_weight) for a [linear code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code) over $GF(2)$.  This problem is NP-hard.  See, e.g.,

Elwyn R. Berlekamp, Robert J. McEliece, and Henk C. A. van Tilborg. [On the Inherent Intractability of Certain Coding Problems](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/5607/1/BERieeetit78.pdf). IEEE Transactions on Information Theory 24 (1978), 384–386.

There are heuristics and algorithms that improve upon brute-force search, and algorithms that can work in polynomial time for certain special cases, but in the general case this is still hard if $n$ is large.

Comment: thank you for answer. are you sure that this problem is exactly the problem that paper discusses about? i think that is another problem, wants to minimize the weight of x such that xA=0, for given A. is there any reduction ?

Comment: @MohammadJavadHajialikhani, I think it's equivalent, if we let $A$ be the [parity check matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix) of the code given by the generator matrix $M$.  (I could be wrong.)